# Python - Access items of a Set by index

Tags: python, set

So I created a set and I need to get items of that set with index like

```
myList = {Baseball,Basketball,Football}
print(myList.getitem(3)) #this should print item 3 of myList
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think data structure you are using is a `Set` and you can just use `myList[2]` to access the item 3. It should not 3 because in Python and many other programming languages, the sequence start from 0, i.e. in your case, your items are indexed as 0, 1, 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first off lists in python are bounded by square brackets. Also, I'm assuming Basketball and Football are variables you've already defined in your script, so you'll have something that looks like this:

```
Basketball = 5
Football = 'a'

myList = [Basketball, Basketball, Football]
```

You can get the value of the third item of this list using an index! Indexing counts from 0, so we'll be calling for index 2 rather than 3

```
myList[2]
```

which will return

```
'a'
```